# Windows 8.1 freeze on startup - Dell Inspiron 15 (7537)

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, mbr, gpt

I have a huge problem. (Sorry for my english) The day befoe yesterday I had a Dell Update shown up on my taskbar, I approved it, it ran, and after that I could not turn my laptop on.

When I try to start it shows me the dell boot screen and it freezes at the login screen OR at desktop OR already at a blank screen before login.

I tried everything, I cannot get to the recovery screen, because somehow Windows thinks that it will boot, and doesn't offer me the recovery option. I didn't made a recovery disk, I have no optical drive, and I had no spare USB drives when I bought the laptop, after that I have forgotten.

I tried to make a bootable Windows 8.1 installation kit on USB, I manage to start it in UEFI mode, System restore cannot succeed, because it cannot access the Windows installation. Auto repair will also not work.

In command prompt I tried to rebuild the boot record, it cannot find any Windows installation (Total identified Windows installations: 0)

I tried to remove C:\Boot\bcd after a tutorial, it says, Path not found - C:\Boot

"bcdboot c:\windows (file:///c:/windows) /s c:" will also not work, it just doesn't recognize the command.

I started a bootable USB with partitioning software. It finds all my drives and all my volumes. OS partition seems to be all right. I wanted to rebuild MBR with the partitioning software, but it can rebuild only MBR and no GPT. At this point I am not sure if I may do it, i want to keep the bootloader in GPT.

I would be able to save some data from the disk, but I don't know if I may reinstall windows from the USB installation kit. I think it may be a partition with the original DELL installation kit, and I don't want to use all the DELL tools from my windows. The best would be to preserve this windows installation.

Can anybody help me further?

Comment: If you have Windows 8.1 you can only use 8.1 installation disk, but your question, indicates you made a 8.0 installation disk.

Comment: No, it is a Windows 8.1 installation disk, I'll try to edit the question. Anyway, it doesn't seem to solve the problem. :(

Comment: It does matter.  Because if you actually used a 8.0 installation disk that would explain the reason it didn't work.

Comment: Okay. I thought, that the repair function is the same in both versions.

Comment: The function is indeed the same, except the image used, is not the same.

Comment: Oh, then I must mention that the USB installation kit is made from a Windows 8.1 Professional ISO and I have the standard Windows 8 version upgraded to 8.1

Comment: The version of Windows 8.1 you have installed isn't important, the recovery .wim image is identical, on both versions.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that. Is there a difference between the "recovery blue screen" of the installed OS and the repair screen of the installation kit? I mean, would I be able to fix my problem if I would be able run the recovery screen and command prompt of my windows installation?

Comment: recovery blue screen is the WinRE partition that exists on your system disk, the exact same WinRE exists on the installation disk, the only difference is it also has the capability to migrate into the WinPE which is used to install Windows.  So if you can't fix the problem from the installation disk (WinRE) it wouldn't work from the WinRE on your system disk anyways.

Comment: Thank you. My next idea was spending the afternoon pushing the F8 key on boot, trying to get into the recovery screen. :)

Comment: If you fail to boot into Windows 8.1 3 times you will automatically be taken to that screen

Comment: That is not happening. I suppose that is the step where it doesn't take me to the login screen (and freezes) but freezes already at a black screen.